# Apache Camel -- Websphere MQ integration

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I have an application using apache-camel solution, and would like to send message to Websphere MQ Server through jms, convert jms property `JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId` to MQMD field `MQMD.MsgId`, so that I set this value on message through camel

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_MSGID, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".getBytes());
```

According to [Apache Camel - IBM MQ integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962569/apache-camel-ibm-mq-integration/45966114#45966114), seems we need another properties setting on destination object. Reference **Setting JMS Provider Options on the Destination** on http://camel.apache.org/jms.html, I provide a custom DestinationResolver for camel jms component, set `mdWriteEnabled`, `mdReadEnabled` for destination object.

```
<bean id="ibmMQServer01" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="ibmMQCredentialConnectionFactory01" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="wmqDestinationResolver" />
</bean>
```

and

```
public class WMQDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver {
    @Override
    public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, 
            boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
        MQSession mqSession = (MQSession) session;
        MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) mqSession.createQueue("queue:///" + destinationName);
        queue.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
        queue.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
        queue.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);
        return queue;
    }
}
```

I can get `JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId` on receiver while setting `mdReadEnabled` equals true. However, `mdWriteEnabled` seems not works for me, and I get `JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId` as an unexpected value `AMQ CS.QA.CBSA.Q�Y�b` (been parsed from byte[], totally 24 bytes).

The received `JMSMessageID` is `ID:414d512043532e51412e434253412e511987055902cc6222`, which can be parsed to the messy string above.

Answer (score 1):

I drill down camel code and find the root casue

While setting jms property, it will run method `getValidJMSHeaderValue` of `org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding`

```
protected Object getValidJMSHeaderValue(String headerName, Object headerValue) {
    if (headerValue instanceof String) {
        return headerValue;
    } else if (headerValue instanceof BigInteger) {
        return headerValue.toString();
    } else if (headerValue instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return headerValue.toString();
    } else if (headerValue instanceof Number) {
        return headerValue;
    } else if (headerValue instanceof Character) {
        return headerValue;
    } else if (headerValue instanceof CharSequence) {
        return headerValue.toString();
    } else if (headerValue instanceof Boolean) {
        return headerValue;
    } else if (headerValue instanceof Date) {
        return headerValue.toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Seems camel reject byte array value and return null, so that jms provider cannot apply property of `JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId`. I override this method to sovle it.

Note: I simply create the same class `org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding` in source folder `src/main/java`, class loader would default load this class instead of the class from maven library.

Comment: Is there a way to submit a bug report to Apache Camel to have this taken care of in upstream?

Answer (score 0):

> I can get JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId on receiver while setting mdReadEnabled
>   equals true. However, mdWriteEnabled seems not works for me, and I get
>   JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId as an unexpected value "AMQ CS.QA.CBSA.Q�Y�b""
>   (been parsed from byte[], totally 24 bytes).
>
> The received JMSMessageID is
>   "ID:414d512043532e51412e434253412e511987055902cc6222", which can be
>   parsed to the messy string above.

What you are seeing is correct.  The MsgId is a byte array of 24 bytes.  It is made up of BOTH string and binary values.  Hence, you CANNOT use it as a String.